# Parameters were incorrect when running Selenium?

Tags: eclipse, macos, selenium, appium-ios

I'm testing my app on mac with real ios device. When i run the scripts it says following error in Eclipse IDE,

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new 
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities 
>   [{app=/Users//Downloads/XXX.ipa,
>   platformVersion=10.2.1, platformName=iOS, deviceName=Mr.x'S iPod touch, 
>   UDID=*****}], required capabilities = 
>   Capabilities [{}]

Then i checked the logs in appium it shows,

> [debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were 
>   incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":
>   ["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent [ 
>   "desiredCapabilities" , "requiredCapabilities", "capabilities", 
>   "alwaysMatch","firstMatch"]

What should i do to fix this, Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Do I need xcode for automating real ios device on mac?

Comment: When i run it on IOS Simulator, the application installed it on simulator but fails to open.I build WebDriverAgentRunner on xcode..When i run appium this webdriveragentrunner also installed with my application. But the application is not opening.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need xcode to access iOS native app.

Desired capabilities to be used:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview", "true");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iphone");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts",true);
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", UDID);
        capabilities.setCapability("xcodeConfigFile", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Config.xcconfig");
        capabilities.setCapability("realDeviceLogger","/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deviceconsole");
```

Comment: Based on the URL you've included containing your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).